# ordered linked list insertion

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a homework assignment where I take in the size of a list and then the elements. I then insert them in increasing order. This code has a push and append method using referencing to the head pointer. If I use an input that is already in increasing order its fine, but pushing onto the front might be the problem is it how I am changing the headRef? Any help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node item;
  struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* next;

};

void insertFront(item** headRef, int new_data)
{

  item* new_node = (item*) malloc(sizeof(item));

  new_node->data  = new_data;

  new_node->next = (*headRef);

  (*headRef)    = new_node;
}

//using reference to pointer adds to end
void insertEnd(item** headRef, int new_data)
{

  item* new_node = (item*) malloc(sizeof(item));

  //pointer head for iterating through list
  item* last = *headRef;  

  new_node->data  = new_data;

  new_node->next = NULL;

  if (*headRef == NULL)
  {
     *headRef = new_node;
     return;
  }

  while (last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;

  last->next = new_node;
  return;
}

//utility function to insert data sorted
void insert_sorted_linked_list(item* head, int val){
 if(val > head->data){
   insertEnd(&head, val);
 }
 else{
  insertFront(&head, val);
 }

}

void printList(item *node)
{
  while (node != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d  ", node->data);
    node = node->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(){

  printf("Enter in size of the list followed by as many elements: ");
  int size;
  scanf("%d", &size);
  int elements[size];
  int i = 0;
  for(i=0; i<size; i++){
  scanf("%d", &elements[i]);
}
item *head = NULL;
//makes sure the list is not null
insertEnd(&head, elements[0]);
//iterates to populate list
for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
  insert_sorted_linked_list(head, elements[i]);
}
printList(head);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: what is the error?? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: sorry, when I use a sample input of 3 321 it should insert into the list in order and output 1 2 3, but if i use said input it only outputs 3.

Comment: `insertEnd(&head, val);` The `head` here is a local paramemter, hence stored in stack, i.e. it will have function scope, hence address of `head` (`&head`) is invalid inside `insertEnd` function. What you are getting is undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `insert_sorted_linked_list()` function to :

```
void insert_sorted_linked_list(item** head, int val){
 if(val > (*head)->data){
   insertEnd(head, val);
 }
 else{
  insertFront(head, val);
 }

}
```

and call it from main as :

```
insert_sorted_linked_list(&head, elements[i]);
```

The changes made to head in calls to `insertFront` and `insertEnd` from this function is not getting reflected in main because of the call by value. Hence in `main()` head remains at 3, the first node inserted. Thats why the output is wrong.